# SQL query for counting records for period of time

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, where-clause

I use SQLITE (with C#) and I have a table like this:

```
Car     PurchaseDate
Ford    2020-07-01
Audi    2020-07-31
Porsche 2020-07-31
Ford    2020-07-28
Audi    2020-07-30
Ford    2020-06-21
Ford    2020-06-21
Audi    2020-06-22
Ford    2020-06-21
Audi    2020-06-22
Porsche 2020-06-22
Ford    2020-08-01
Audi    2020-08-01
Porsche 2020-08-10
```

I need a SQL-query that would give me the count per Car for a given timeperiod.
(PurchaseDate is of type varchar not datetime)

So for example for the above data:
Timeperiod\PurchaseDate: 2020-06-01 - 2020-06-31

Result should be:

```
Ford    3
Audi    2
Porsche 1
```

Comment: There is no 2020-06-31.  Good reason to use a real date data type.

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
select car, count(*) no_cars
from mytable
where purchase_date >= '2020-06-01' and purchase_date < '2020-07-01'
group by car
```